# Почему функция не отрабатывает сразу после вызова?

Tags: javascript

У меня довольно большой код, и пока он отрабатывает, хочу, чтоб запускалась анимация (спиннер крутящийся). Но анимация начинает проигрываться только после отработки всего кода, либо выключается сразу же после включения. Есть две функции: одна - на включение спиннера, другая - на выключение. По задумке анимация должна начинать работать только после второго клика по кнопке.

**P.S.** проверял тем, что добавлял запрос в консоль внутри этих функций - в консоль запросы выводятся когда нужно, но анимация не работает.

**P.P.S** возможно, проблема в том, что на самом деле у меня не один обработчик, а много обработчиков кликов, вложенных один в другой (мой косяк, но не смог придумать, как сделать по-другому). И пока они все не отработают, анимация не загрузится. Может быть, можно второй раз повесить обработчик на ту же кнопку, но уже вначале, вне основного кода? И тогда анимация отработает сразу? Но тогда, получается, анимация не будет знать, когда ей останавливаться. Можно наверно включающую анимацию поместить отдельно, а выключающую - после выполнения кода...

```js
const button = document.getElementById('button');
let counterTurg;

function downloadAnimIn(e) {
  if (counterTurg >= 1) {
    let loadingIn = () => {
      if (!document.querySelector('.downloader').classList.contains('active')) {
        document.querySelector('.downloader').classList.add('active');
      }
    };
    loadingIn();
    console.log(counterTurg);  //в консоле сведенья появляются сразу, 
                               //а анимация не работает
  }
};

function downloadAnimOut(e) {
  if (counterTurg >= 1) {
    let loadingOut = () => {
      if (document.querySelector('.downloader').classList.contains('active')) {
         document.querySelector('.downloader').classList.remove('active');
      }
    };
    loadingOut();
    console.log('====' + counterTurg);
  }
};

function buttonPush(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  
  downloadAnimIn(e);
  
  //код ....
  //код ....
  //код ....
  
  
  downloadAnimOut(e);

  counterTurg = 0;

  counterTurg++;
}

button.addEventListener('click, buttonPush);
```

```css
.downloader {
  padding: 20px;
  background: red;
  display: none;
 }
 
 .active {
  display: block;
 }
```

```html
<button type='button' id='button'>Button</button>
<div class='downloader'>Spinner</div>
```

Comment: JS я не очень знаю, но полагаю, что если вы выполняете какой-то долгий код в обработчике события UI, то другие события UI при этом не могут обрабатываться, они ждут, пока завершится ваш код обработчика события. Запускайте там отдельный поток, ну или таймер, и делайте логику там, тогда события UI будут нормально обрабатываться.

Comment: Так у меня не "другое событие" - у меня на одном событии висит и "долгий код" и анимация, причем анимация - сразу после события.

Comment: Пока главный поток не освободиться - никакие действия выполняться не будут. Придется тебе переделывать алгоритм...

Comment: Так анимация как сделана? Если для её обработки движку нужно обрабатывать какие-то свои события, то они не смогут обработаться из-за вашего "долгого кода". Обработка начнётся только после окончания всего вашего кода.

Comment: Запомните главное правило, оно для любых языков и фреймворков работает. Обработчик события UI должен как можно быстрее вернуть управление. Можно поменять какое-то состояние, взвести какие-то таймеры, ещё что-то такое сделать, чтобы потом всё нужное отработало. Но управление из обработчика нужно вернуть как можно быстрее, иначе ничего работать не будет.

Comment: Пример, что тут приведен вообще по ошибке вылетает. :(

Comment: CrazyElf, спасибо! Все заработало!! :)) Обновил ответ!

Comment: Хорошо, что разобрались в итоге. Я забыл, что в JS даже и потоков нет. Но про таймеры помнил )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Удалил свой первый ответ, так как он неправильный.
Мой вопрос не имеет решения.
Так как JavaScript - язык однопоточный (т.е. может выполняться только одна задача в один момент времени), невозможно одновременно запустить две функции - они все равно попадут в очередь стека вызовов - одна за одной.
Подробнее: https://habr.com/ru/companies/hexlet/articles/656003/

**UPD.**  Как и советовал  CrazyElf, повесил на первый обработчик на этой кнопке таймер:

```
positBtn.addEventListener('click', function () { setTimeout(turgetCheck, 0) });
```

, и все заработало :))

Comment: не совсем так, есть webworker, в которые можно вынести вычисления

Comment: и? На одном потоке можно выполнять несколько задач. До 2000 года почти все ПК были "однопоточными" (точнее, с одним ядром), но далеко не "однозадачными"

Comment: Mikhail Ionkin И? Я это знаю, вопрос был не в этом